# how to install QGIS 2.2.0 on mac OS 10.6.8?

Tags: qgis, mac

Does someone know how to install the latest QGIS on a mac os 10.6.8? The dmg package available on http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis does not run on my OS version.
I was only able to find a developement version of QGIS from Sept 2013 which is not fully stable.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [Installer package QGIS 2.2 OSX 10.6?](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Installerpackage-QGIS-2-2-OSX-10-6-td5108184.html)

1) You can install the master version of QGIS compiled every day by Larry Shaffer ([Dakcarto](http://qgis.dakotacarto.com/) - Snow Leopard version). It is the development version (2.3) and so there may be bugs (reminder: **one new version every day**). It uses the [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/) Frameworks and in the event the supporting frameworks will not install for 10.6, that nightly will be suspended

2) Or you change your strategy and you install all with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (look at [Homebrew-osgeo4mac](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac))

Comment: Thanks, the Homebrew option is exactly what I was looking for!! And yes, the development version is unstable for certain things.

Answer (score 3):

You can try compiling it yourself using [the OSGeo4Mac Homebrew tap](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac).

Install XCode and [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), then:

```sh
brew update
brew tap homebrew/science
brew tap osgeo/osgeo4mac
brew info qgis-22
# review the options you want for install, e.g. --with-grass --with-globe
brew install qgis-22  [--with-options...]
```

The install on Mac 10.6.8 using OSGeo4Mac has not been fully tested (will be soon). You may run into issues, specifically if using Apple's older `gcc-4.2` compiler, instead of `clang`.

Please report any issues you have with formulae from that tap to the [OSGeo4Mac tracker](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/issues). Other formulae issues, from upstream Homebrew taps, should be reported on their respective trackers.